# Get Python command used to run the current Python script

Tags: python

If I run a Python script, `foo.py` with

```
$ python3.6 foo.py
```

`sys.argv` will return `['foo.py']`. But I want something that will return the name of the command used to launch the script. In this case `'python3.6'`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you’re looking for [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable):

> A string giving the absolute path of the executable binary for the Python interpreter, on systems where this makes sense. If Python is unable to retrieve the real path to its executable, `sys.executable` will be an empty string or `None`.

This is commonly used for things like running another Python script via `subprocess.run([sys.executable, 'spam.py', 'arg')`.

This gives you the absolute path to the Python interpreter. If you want just the name, use [`os.path.basename(sys.executable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename).

Keep in mind that it’s always possible that, say, `/usr/local/bin/python3.6` is actually just a symlink or even a shim launcher for something named, say, `/opt/local/python3.6/bin/python3`, in which case you might get the latter path, and basenaming it would then give you `python3`, but then running `python3` might  run a different `python3` that’s higher on the path. Using the absolute path, you won’t have that problem.